# Disabling LetsEncrypt on Apache

Tags: apache2, encryption, lamp, letsencrypt

I installed Wordpress on my site via [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial. One of the prerequisites is to secure Apache with Let's Encrypt and there is a tutorial that I followed for that [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Unfortunately I am finding that enabling this security has blocked access to some of my subdomains that are located on different servers which do not have support for TLS/SSL certificates. So I'd like to try to remove or disable this security and I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Please post as answer so other will benefit...

Comment: You could also add an automatic redirect from http(80) to https(443) on apache

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I used to solve this problem. First, enter this command in the terminal:

```
sudo a2dismod ssl
```

Then restart apache2 with this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then just make sure you clear your browser history so it doesn't automatically redirect to https. This was for Ubuntu 16.04